# in yii2 ,how to get column heading of gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2

"I have a gridview in my project. now i want column heading back in a array. which method should i use???see code.."

```
<?php

    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
    /* @var $this yii\web\View */
    /* @var $model app\models\Companies */

    $this->title = 'Export File';//'Create Companies';
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Companies', 'url' => ['index']];
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
    $allColumnsDBArray = $model->getTableSchema()->getColumnNames();
    //problem is here it is giving column heading of mysql database table
?>

<div class="companies-create">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Export CSV',  ['class' => 'btn btn-primary','name' => 'export']) ?>

        <?php echo "<br>";      
        foreach ($allColumnsDBArray as $colHeading) {
            echo $colHeading; echo "<br>"; 
        }?>

    </div>
</div>
```

"but it gives column heading of in mysql database??and requirment is of gridview column heading??"

Comment: You can use custom attribute labels in you model   `$model->getAttributeLabel('attribute_name');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your model class. it has method called attributesLabels. Use it for your solution.

```
$model          =   new ModelName();
print_r($model->attributeLabels());
```

If this don't fit for your requirement then create new method in model with your required labels,

```
public function getGridLabels(){
  return [
     "id"         => "Id",
     "first_name" => "First Name",
     "email"      => "Email",
  ];

}
```

Call it as below

```
$model->getGridLabels();
```

Answer (score 0):

For get all the header/ label of a model You can use

```
 $model->attributes();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#attributes()-detail

Answer (score 0):

For obtain the attributeLabel

```
$model->attributeLabels();
```

[image]